# Mahalanobis distance based classifier leads to seemingly wrong scores for points identical to training data

Tags: r, statistics, distance, modeling, raster

I have been using the mahal classifier function (Dismo package in r) in several of my analyses and recently I have discovered that it seems to give apparently wrong distance results for points that are identical to points used in training of the classifier. For background, from what I understand of mahalanobis-based classifiers, is that they use Mahalanobis distance to describe the similarity of a unclassified point by measuring the point's distance from the center of mass of the training set (while accounting for differences in scale and covariance, etc.). The mahalanobis distance score varies from –inf to 1, where one indicates no distance between the unclassified point and the centroid defined by the training set. However, I found that, for all points with identical predictor values than the training points, I still get a score of 1, as if the routine is working as a nearest neighbor classifier. This is a very troubling behavior because it has the potential to artificially increase the confidence of my overall classification.

**Has anyone encountered this behavior? Any ideas on how to fix/ avoid this behavior?**

I have written a small script below that showcases the odd behavior clearly:

```
rm(list = ls()) #remove all past worksheet variables
library(dismo)
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

#presence data (points that fall within the 'r' in the R logo)
pts <- matrix(c(48.243420, 48.243420, 47.985820, 52.880230, 49.531423, 46.182616, 
                54.168232, 69.624263, 83.792291, 85.337894, 74.261072, 83.792291, 95.126713, 
                84.565092, 66.275456, 41.803408, 25.832176, 3.936132, 18.876962, 17.331359, 
                7.048974, 13.648543, 26.093446, 28.544714, 39.104026, 44.572240, 51.171810, 
                56.262906, 46.269272, 38.161230, 30.618865, 21.945145, 34.390047, 59.656971, 
                69.839163, 73.233228, 63.239594, 45.892154, 43.252326, 28.356155), ncol=2)
# fit model
m <- mahal(logo, pts)

#using model, predict train data
training_vals=extract(logo, pts)
x <- predict(m, training_vals)
x #results show a perfect 1 prediction, which is highly unlikely
```

Now, I try to make predictions for values that are an average for directly adjacent point pairs
I do this because given that: 
(1) each point for each pair used to train the model have a perfect suitability and 
(2) that at least some of these average points are likely to be as close to the center of the mahalanobis centroid than the original pairs
(3) I would expect at least a few of the average points to have a perfect suitability as well.

```
#pick two adjacent points and fit model
adjacent_pts=pts
adjacent_pts[,2]=adjacent_pts[,2]+1
adjacent_training_vals=extract(logo, adjacent_pts)
new_pts=rbind(pts, adjacent_pts)
plot(logo[[1]]) #plot predictor raster and response point pairs 
points(new_pts[,1],new_pts[,2])

#use model to predict mahalanobis score for new training data (point pairs)
m <- mahal(logo, new_pts)
new_training_vals=extract(logo, new_pts)
x <- predict(m, new_training_vals) 
x
```

As expected from the odd behavior described, all training points have a distance score of 1. However, lets try to predict points that are an average of each pair:

```
mid_vals=(adjacent_training_vals+training_vals)/2
x <- predict(m, mid_vals)
x #NONE DO!
```

This for me is further indication that the Mahal routine will give a perfect score for any data point that has equal values to any of the points used to train the model

This below is uncessessary, but just another way to prove the point:
Here I predict the same original train data with a near insignificant 'budge' of values for only one of the predictors and show that the resulting scores change quite significantly.

```
mod_training_vals=training_vals
mod_training_vals[,1]=mod_training_vals[,1]*1.01
x <- predict(m, mod_training_vals)
x #predictions suddenly are far from perfect predictions
```

Comment: I'm not sure mahalanobis algorithm does exactly what you are expecting; it's not completely clear from your description. So try this: calculate the mahal. dist. for a few specific points and compare to where they lie on the plane.  So far as I can tell, your only dimensions are x and y (no color or intensity data, e.g.) so the mahal. dist should be reduced to the Euclidean distance function.  Can you check that too?

Comment: I wish that was the case. However, according to the documentation (and supported by my calculations), the mahal function when fed a raster stack of predictors will treat the two-column matrix of points as spatial points used to extract the predictor values from the stack.